# Trial SharePoint development VMs?

Tags: sharepoint

I was looking for trial SharePoint VMs (2013 and/or 2016) but have failed at finding any. Is Microsoft still providing VMs for download?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2013/07/15/step-by-step-build-a-free-sharepoint-2013-devtest-lab-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-infrastructure-services/) to create your SP lab with Azure. More information can be found at Microsoft social technet - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/865e5de5-0bfd-45b4-9c32-3d1a9837baf3/sharepoint-server-2013-virtual-machine-available-to-download?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[SharePoint Server 2016 Virtual Machine Download (Updated March 2018)](https://gauravmahajan.net/2017/10/06/sharepoint-server-2016-virtual-machine-download/)

And create SharePoint Trial VM in Azure:

[Create virtual machines in Azure
 SharePoint 2016 trial tutoria](https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint2016/VM-Azure.htm)